# Include 31 days if respective month contains, while calculating difference between two dates in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

i need to show exactly difference between two dates.
This is exactly what i am doing

```
func getDifferenceBetween(dateString1:String, dateString2:String) -> String {
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date1 = formatter.date(from: dateString1)
let date2 = formatter.date(from: dateString2)

let form = DateComponentsFormatter()
form.maximumUnitCount = 2
form.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
form.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .day]
let difference = (form.string(from: date1!, to: date2!))?.capitalized

print("difference- \(difference)")
 return difference!
}
```

the problem is it is not considering if month contains 31 days or if year is leap year.

for example:

```
dateString1 = "2017-04-08 13:31:19" 
dateString2 = "2017-06-21 11:17:11" 

getting difference  = 2M 12D
should get difference = 2M 15D
```

Comment: Why do you expect "2M 15D" for those two dates? April 8 to June 8 is 2 months. Then June 8, 13:31:19 to June 21 11:17:11 is 12 days (almost 13). So the result of "2M 12D" is correct.

Comment: if we think generally we will get 75 days. so should get difference as 2M 15D

Comment: But that assumes months are 30 days. Of course not all months are 30 days so that's not how it works. You can't think about how many days are between the two dates if you want the difference in months and days. Jan 15 - Feb 15 is 1 month. Feb 15 - Mar 15 is 1 month, etc. The actual number of days is irrelevant.

Comment: @BhagyashreeMyanamwar the problem you are having here is that you seem to have defined "one month" as "a period of time that is 30 days long". That definition does not exist anywhere. It is not correct. A month is not a fixed length of time or number of days. Get rid of that definition and you will see that ready is correct.

Answer (score -1):

This a part of code. It's give you days and months between 2 dates using the current user calendar.

```
func getDifferenceBetween(dateString1:String, dateString2:String) -> String {

    let currentCalendar = Calendar.current

    // Format and check dates
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    guard let date1 = formatter.date(from: dateString1),
        let date2 = formatter.date(from: dateString2),
        let m1 = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.month], from: date1).month,
    let m2 = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.month], from: date2).month,
    let d1 = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1).day,
    let d2 = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date2).day

    else { return "Invalid Dates"
    }

    let months = m2 - m1
    let days = d2 - d1


    let difference = "\(months)M, \(days)D"
    return difference
}


getDifferenceBetween(dateString1: "2017-04-08 13:31:19",
                     dateString2: "2017-06-21 11:17:11")
```

I don't understand why do you expect 2M 15D. I hope it can help.
Remark use Guard statement and try to never use ! in your code.

Comment: The code in the question is much better than the code in this answer. How does this answer help with the question? This code will fail in many cases.

Comment: if we think generally then the general difference is 2M 15D . so thats why client was asking to me to show like this.

Comment: @BhagyashreeMyanamwar No, if you think about it generally, it's 2M 12D just as I explained in my comments. You only get 2M 15D in this specific example if you assume months have 30 days.

Comment: This code  returns "2M, -7D" for the difference from "2017-04-08 00:00:00" to "2017-06-01 00:00:00"

Comment: @rmaddy ok Thankyou

Answer (score -2):

May be it's code is better for you ? It adjust day depending on hours of each date

```
func getDifferenceBetween(dateString1:String, dateString2:String) -> String {

    let currentCalendar = Calendar.current

    // Format and check dates
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    guard let date1 = formatter.date(from: dateString1),
        let date2 = formatter.date(from: dateString2),
        let m1 = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.month], from: date1).month,
    let m2 = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.month], from: date2).month,
    let d1 = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1).day,
    let d2 = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date2).day

    else { return "Invalid Dates"
    }

    // Calc Days and Month betwwen two dates
    let months = m2 - m1
    var days = d2 - d1

    // Compare Hours
    if currentCalendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second],
                                      from: date1, to: date2).hashValue > 0 {
        days = days - 1
    }


    let difference = "\(months)M, \(days)D"
    return difference
}


getDifferenceBetween(dateString1: "2017-04-08 13:31:19",
                     dateString2: "2017-06-21 11:17:11")
```

Comment: You should edit your existing answer rather than add a new one.

Comment: This code returns "2M, -8D" for the difference from "2017-04-08 00:00:00" to "2017-06-01 00:00:00". – I wonder what the purpose of checking the hash value of the date components is ...